# Connecting webapp to user's BigQuery project

Tags: google-app-engine, web-applications, google-bigquery, google-authentication

I have made a webapp using streamlit framework that can connect to BigQuery project of a user to fetch the required table and perform certain operations on it and result the output. Rightnow, we are getting the link to the authentication code on the command line. Since we are now planing to deploy the app on the google app engine, is there any way to authenticate a user some other way (other than getting authentication link on CLI since it wouldn't be possible after deployment on app engine).

Comment: Have you tried what is suggested in this page? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/authentication/end-user-installed

Comment: Yes. When I tried the steps mentioned above, I get prompted by the error: OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use.

Comment: Can you let me know which step exactly caused this error?

Comment: appflow.run_local_server(). This is where it's causing the error.

Comment: Perhaps you can open a new issue on IssueTracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187149&template=1162659